# JOGL setup on Mountain Lion

Tags: java, macos, osx-lion, jogl

I am trying to setup JOGL on Mountain Lion. I want to use it without an IDE like Eclipse or sth. but I just can't get it work.

What I did:

- Downloaded the latest JOGL build from here: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL#Downloading_the_latest_automatic_build
- Put the files jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar - gluegen-java-src.zip - jogl-all.jar - gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar - jogl-java-src.zip - gluegen-rt.jar (like it is described in the link above, at least I understood it like this) in a directory: ~/jogl
- Next step: configure classpath. On my system the CLASSPATH variable is empty at the moment. So I added my jars once with their full name, like export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:~/jogl/gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar:~/jogl/...
- tried to compile the testcode. Error: javax.media.opengl does not exist
- tried to change the classpath to match all files with an wildcard "*" -> same issue
- tried to compile with javac -classpath "~/jogl/*" source.java, same error
- added all files seperately to javac -classpath, same error

This question maybe extremely simple and obvious to solve but I would not ask here if I had not tried almost everything to get it work!

Here is the test code I used:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      // setup OpenGL Version 2
      GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
      GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);

      // The canvas is the widget that's drawn in the JFrame
      GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
      glcanvas.addGLEventListener(new Renderer());
      glcanvas.setSize( 300, 300 );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Hello World" );
        frame.getContentPane().add( glcanvas);

        // shutdown the program on windows close event
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.setSize( frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize() );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

My system:
 - OSX 10.8.2
 - javac 1.6.0_35

Comment: Only gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar must be in the classpath. The JARs containing the native libraries for JOGL 2.0 and GlueGen must be in the same directory but not in the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (with jogl-all.jar in the same directory as test.java):

```
javac -classpath jogl-all.jar test.java
```

Your code references a class called Renderer() which isn't supplied so I can't get your example to compile, but this one jar includes `javax.media.opengl.*`

Comment: thx a lot this did it for me...
it even works with multiple jars in a way like
javac -classpath jogl-all.jar:gluegen-rt.jar test.java